# Customer support chat using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, livechat

I am working on some laravel project in which i want to provide live chat for customer services. Customer fill some information then chat will be start for example you can see demo https://www.telenor.com.pk/ or http://www.mobilink.com.pk/. There is a lot of other example I think that two is enough for understand what i want. I want some thing like that please suggest me any library or some helping material that can help me

Comment: The title here is very misleading, it sounds like you're trying to make a support chart for laravel issues.

Comment: yes i want customer support live chat

Comment: Yes but its not **for** laravel it's **using** laravel.

Comment: sorry i'm not understand what you are trying to saying

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand you.

I mean if you want to use that kind of service on your laravel project, just simply register at one of live chat providers.

For example: https://www.tawk.to/ (it's free)

Its very easy to install. You will need just to add website in tawk, and put the javascript that you will get in your template.

Comment: https://www.tawk.to/  that you mentioned in which there is also a chat bottom of right side by title "let's chat? online"  for the customer i want exactly the same

Comment: @MuhammadUmar so register at tawk.to and add chat to your website. You can customise chat in Admin Panel (change colors, texts, language etc.).

Comment: Just made a tawk.to package for Laravel: https://github.com/emotality/tawk-laravel